# I'm stuck with arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, nsarray, relationship

I've got objects in an array, lowAnd[], and every object in this array has a relationship with 0 to many other objects (Goals).
How can I put this objects, Goals, in another array?
Some objects in lowAnd are connected with 2 Goals, some are connected with 4.. (dynamic user editing)
I don't know in advance how many Goals will be connected to a certain object from the array lowAnd?
How do I solve this?
Maybe in a for-loop?
Maybe in a 2-dimensioned-array? 
I 'm really stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

Well 2-dimensional array is good solution but, instead of using for loop, you can use predicates to add objects in lowAnd[]. Apply predicate on Goals array and add resultant array in lowAnd array.